# Can I migrate the hosting of my CDN configured site?

Tags: web-hosting, cdn

My site is CloudFlare Free CDN configured & I am planning to migrate my hosting. Can I do so, since its CDN configured?

Comment: Isn't it just connected to CloudFlare via your current host?  Can't you just disable that?

Comment: Cloudflare doesn't host your site, it reserve proxies it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you want to only change your hosting, and keep your current settings via Cloudflare.

If that is the case...

All you need to do is, on your CloudFlare DNS Zone File page, change your “A” record’s IP address of your old host to your new hosts IP address.